# Let's get a canonical Q&A about PS4 controllers not connecting

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[image: "Related" list of PS4 controller troubles on a question about PS4 controllers]

Somehow, many people have trouble with connecting controllers to their PS4, and new questions asking how to solve the issue are still being asked.
It would be helpful to have a single question and answer listing the most common causes of connectivity problems and the steps to solve them, similarly to [I can't play Pokemon GO! What's wrong?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274535/i-cant-play-pokemon-go-whats-wrong).

(If we already have such a question, please link it here to make it easy to find when casting close votes)

Comment: I suggest having two of them - one for connection to PS4 itself and another for PC connection - with references between them.

Comment: [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/263064/28182) is pretty canonical in terms of the controller -> PS4 side. Dunno about the controller -> PC side

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/291828/ps4-controller-bluetooth-usb-connection-trouble this question looks good for Windows PC connection

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/147336/144891 and this one has good info about connection to  Mac